# Instead of a href display content directly below after clicking the button

Tags: html, button

[image]

Is there a simple way to display the content directly below by clicking a button? Right now I'm doing it over an `<a href>`:

```
<tr><td><a href="##" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://test.cfm', '_blank','width=900,height=880, toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,statu s=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=no'); return false;">TEST1</a></tr><td>
```

see also attachment.

Thank you for your help and tips and tricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target website allows it, you could use an iframe (no Javascript necessary) or AJAX.

```html
<p>
  <a href="https://example.com" target="the_frame">Click me!</a>
</p>

<iframe name="the_frame"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use css to achieve this. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKqPwj) for solution.

This div with class row is the one we want to show and hide on click of button.

```
<button id="toggleSlider">Toggle Slider</button>
<div class="row">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim minus repellat amet nobis hic dolores blanditiis inventore quo ex quaerat omnis accusantium adipisci velit laborum facilis culpa nemo ab placeat!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

On click of button we add a class to  toggle a class `.slide-up` which will hide the div

```
.slide-up {
  height:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px none;
}
```

The codepen was edited based on the question asked [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893850/issues-with-fully-collapsible-div)